# Is snowflake generated ID can be bigger then unsigned_long? (2^64-1)

Tags: elasticsearch, twitter-snowflake

It's a bit stupid question, but I don't have enough relevant expirience to answer it myself.

Can a snowflake generated ID (`274950720577339394`), be bigger then `unsigned_long` type of integer? (2^64-1)

Just a bit more info. I'd like to store snowflake IDs inside the elasticsearch index, and according to it's [integer types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html) there is a `unsigned_long` which I guess should perfectly fit, and store snowflake as a number. So doesn't it a good idea? Or it's safe to use `keyword` instead of `int` types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they can't.

According to [this post on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/g/twitter-development-talk/c/UVKjSormzLY),

> IDs will still be 64-bit unsigned integers

Note that this post was posted in 2010, which is a while ago, but it doesn't seem it was changed.

Comment: Yes, I have also checked Wiki article about it, seems snowflakes are strict >=64bits, unless you are not dealing with customize version of it, like Instagramm UUID.